# How to Unmarshal jSON with dynamic key which can't be captured as a `json` in struct: GOlang

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I have this struct defined:

```
type X struct {
 A string `json:"a_known_string"`
 B string `json:"b_known_string"`
}
```

This sample JSON:

jsnStr := [read in from a file and printed out to confirm]

It is:

```
{
 "any string" : {
   "a_known_string" : "some value",
   "b_known_string" : "another value" 
 }
}
```

If it was just the struct, I could:

```
var x X
err := json.Unmarshal(jsnStr, &x)
```

But I need to capture that 'any string'.
How do I do that please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a map:

```
var m map[string]X
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsnStr), &m)
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/LgjMCMPr1N)

Comment: The error i get is: 'Cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string'  should I use an array of map of string to X instead?  (trying that code)... Will comment here whether it works.

Comment: My error was related to the structure X => which contained a few 'numbers' instead of strings' and hence the failures.  The map solution you provided @MuffinTop, works exactly as expected.  Thank you.

Comment: If the JSON contains numbers, then declare the corresponding struct fields using a numeric type (int, float64, ...).